# Request REST POST API work in Postman but in Alamofire don't work

Tags: swift, alamofire, postman

I have an api that return a very simple JSON.

**First the server that contains the api was in my local machine (localhost), in this case, all work fine.**

I passed the api to the web hosting, when I tried to connect from the iPhone App (using Alamofire) to the hosting api don't work

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://domain.com/api/search", parameters: ["ubicacion": ubicacionId, "fecha":"\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(fecha))"], encoding: .URL)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // URL response
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                    self.JSON = response.result.value!
                    //llamar el delegate
                    self.delegate.devolverjson(self.JSON)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // URL response
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                    self.JSON = ["error":error]
                    //llamar el delegate
                    self.delegate.devolvererror(self.JSON)
                }
        }
```

In this case the `response.response` are:

```
{ URL: https://domain.com/api/search } { status code: 405, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, private";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 07 Jul 2016 18:24:26 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=3, max=30";
    Server = "Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.22";
    allow = POST;
} })
```

The `response.result` is `.Failure`

And the error are

```
error: {
    error = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"Invalid value around character 0.\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}";
}
```

When I connect to the api (the same URL:https://domain.com/api/search ) from Postman the api returns the correct information (JSON), whit this headers.

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Thu, 07 Jul 2016 18:23:38 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=3, max=30
Server →Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Powered-By →PHP/5.6.22
```

Why if the API work with Postman, don't work with Alamofire?

Excuse me if the english is not correct

Comment: I think that your postman parameter key's are not the same as request keys

Comment: The key's are the same, however if the key's were different the Content-type should be JSON @AkshanshThakur

Comment: have same problem

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem today. My fix was to change encoding for the request.

I switched between `URLEncoding()` and `JSONEncoding.default`

You can try various other encodings that work for your request.

Comment: you save my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add trailing slash to your url:

`https://domain.com/api/search/`

Comment: Why and how? :/ Worked for me , but seems annoying solution

Answer (score 0):

Does the response.request match the url you tried in Postman?
Did you try Alamofire.request(.GET, url) instead of .POST?
I had some issue with the parameters in one project so instead I formated my url before and used Alamofire without parameters but with the formated url.

Comment: Yes, is the same URL. And when i trie to use .GET instead of .POST, the status code is 403 instead 405 that get when use I POST

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error in Swift 4.2 Xcode 10.

I was using the URL in Postman as : `18.222.156.118/Service/v1/SignIn` and passing the parameter

`UserPhone:7021844116
RequestCd:R28`

It was working correctly in Postman.

When I used the same URL in `Alamofire`

```
    let parameters: Parameters = ["UserPhone": self.textfieldPhoneNumber.text!,
                                  "RequestCd": "R28"]

    // All three of these calls are equivalent
    Alamofire.request("18.222.156.118/Service/v1/SignIn",method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        print("Result: \(String(describing: response.request))")
        print("Result: \(String(describing: response.response))")
        print("Result: \(response.result)")
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)

        if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
            print("JSON VALUE --- \(json)")
            if json["ErrorCode"] as?  Int ==  0 {
              print("got success")

            }else{
                 Print("error")
            }
        }
    }
```

I got error `Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"`
I added the `http://` at initial.

Correct URL is `http://18.222.156.118/Service/v1/SignIn`
It worked finally.
 Since google Postman internally adds hhttp:\.